# Транслитерация армянских имени и фамилии Ованес и Ованисян

Tags: транслитерация

Я работаю в отделе русского языка одного из армянских СМИ. Хочу поделиться с Вами одним спорным вопросом в армянской журналисткой среде и попросить Вас найти решение для него. Речь идет о том, как нужно писать на русском языке армянское имя Hovhannes и фамилию Hovhannisyan (лат. транслит.). Имя, как правило, пишут Ованес (например, великий армянский писатель [Ованес Туманян](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BD,_%D0%9E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81_%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)), но фамилию многие пишут Ованнисян, другие же предпочитают Ованисян. Как носитель языка отмечу, что в обоих случаях произносится 1 н (произносится hованес и hованисян, h в транлитерации опускают). Учитывая, что Ованес пишут через 1 н, я считаю целесообразным писать Ованисян тоже через 1 н, поскольку у них один и тот же корень. Однако многие специалисты не согласны с этим и пишут Ованнисян через 2 н. Помогите, пожалуйста, разрешить эту проблему на основании принятых в русском языке норм. Заранее благодарю.

С уважением,
А. Овсепян

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Большой Советской Энциклопедии варианта *Ованнисян* нет. Есть:

Ованисян Нар Михайлович.

Мурацан Григор (псевдоним; настоящая фамилия Тер-Ованисян).

Нар-Дос (псевдоним; настоящая фамилия и имя Ованисян Микаэл Захарьевич).

Среди чемпионов Универсиады – сов. легкоатлет И. А. Тер-Ованесян.

Очерки истории СССР. М., 1958. С. Н. Ованесян.

Всё о спорте. М., 1972. Тер-Ованесян А. А.

Н. А. Вартапетян. Справочник по русской транскрипции армянских имен, фамилий и географических названий.

В русской транскрипции армянских собственных имен наблюдается разнобой. Широкие круги общественности издавна ожидают справочника или инструкции, которые способствовали бы единству транскрипции армянских имен. Этой цели как раз и призвана служить книга Н. А. Вартапетяна, предназначенная для широкого круга общественности, в частности для работников печати и радио, переводчиков, работников государственных и общественных организаций, географических обществ, учителей русского языка армянских школ.

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?hl=ru&nfpr=1&num=100&lr=&ft=i&cr=&safe=images&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=238352l238352l0l240666l1l1l0l0l0l0l511l511l5-1l1l0&q=cache:akTauTaoJsEJ:http://basss.asj-oa.am/2254/1/1962-12(117).pdf+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0+%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9&ct=clnk

Comment: Спасибо за ценную информацию из авторитетных источников. Это то, что нужно!

Answer (score 2):

В русском языке, кроме перечисленных, есть еще вариант (на мой взгляд, самый логичный) - Ованесян (от имени Ованес).
Удвоенной Н тут не должно быть: в имени Ованес, от которого происходит фамилия, одно Н, а кроме того, в фамилии Ованесян удвоение не звучит.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Звучит вполне логично, но, чтобы переубедить некоторых, нужны какие-то ссылки на официальные источники по правилам. Если у Вас есть такие источники, очень прошу отметить.

Спасибо

Comment: Оваргар, а почему вы не возразили против написания фамилии через Е?
Там же в оригинальном написании явное ի. - 
Например тут: Վահան Հովհաննիսյան
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BD,_%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%AD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87

Comment: Не возразил, так как иногда в арм. встречается вариант Ованесян, хотя больше распространен вариант с измененной гласной, т.е. с И, а также потому, что в данном вопросе меня интересует Н, а не гласные. С гласными проблем не бывает.

Comment: Ах вон оно как... т.е. в армянских фамилиях тоже встречаются колебания в основе. Для меня это новость. Но вопрос я этот задавал не ради самой буквы Е/И как таковой а чтобы иметь некоторые основания для ответа на ваш вопрос относительно удвоения согласной. 
Я поясню свою мысль. Я ориентировался на предположении об абсолютной "правильности" фонетичесного написания армянских фамилий в языке-оригинале. При таком положении логично было бы следовать и принципу абсолютной транслитерации во всех случаях, включая не только рссматриваемое чередование Е/И (Ованес-Ованисян), но и разбираемое Н/НН.

Comment: Своим ответом вы несколько поколебали мою уверенность. В такой ситуации и с учетом сложившийся практики может быть и следует отойти от абсолютной транслитерации в пользу фонетического транскрибирования, как тут и предлагалось. Возражения по поводу нежелательности передачи նն через одинарное Н снимаю. Попробую спросить насчет литературы, но не обещаю. очень уж специфический момент...

Answer (score 2):

Источника указать не могу, но есть практическое правило.
Имена собственные, закрепившиеся в языке надо писать так, как они закрепились. Неизвестные - как можно ближе к оригиналу. Последнее правило не всегда формализуемо, понятие о близости у всех разное, но в отношении одного или двух Н, думаю, оно вполне понятно.

Поэтому я однозначно за Ованес как хорошо известную форму и за Ованнисян. Насколько знаю, армянские фамилии в отличие от русских не допускают колебаний в написании на языке-оригинале, поэтому форму фамилии полагаю единственно правильной. 
Это не касается нескольких исторических Ованесянов, Аванесянов, Аванесовых и проч. Фактически такие фамилии следует считать *русскими* фамилиями иноязычного происхождения. К ним правило неприменимо.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Многие русские эту фамилию транслитерируют "Оганесян", отсюда и "Оганезов". Однако в отношении "Ованес" и "Ованнисян" я считаю, что это однокоренные слова и следует быть последовательным - либо оба с 2 Н, либо оба с 1 Н. Представьте Вашу реакцию, если бы в русском писали Иван с 1 Н, а ИванНов - с 2 Н(Ованес - это Иван по арм.,от греч. Иоаннес). Что касается близости к оригиналу, то Ованнисян вовсе не близок, так как в арм. не произносится удвоенное Н, а транслитерация - это передача звучания оригинального слова, а не написания.

Comment: Оваргар, спасибо.
Отвечаю по пунктам. Вам и всем

1. С "Оганесяном" проблем нет. Я знаю происхождение этого варинта фамилии. Но я не думаю, что тут следует говорить о транслитерации. В большинстве случаев это опять-таки закрепление фонетического принципа, т.е. явление, близкое к транскрибированию.

Comment: 2. Иван и Иваннов. В русском подобные вещи на каждом шагу. Одна и та же фамилия может существовать в десятках вариантов. Кононов и Коннонов, нрапример. Вполне допускаю, что среди них есть и Иваннов. Всё дело в том, что в русском - не в пример армянскому - основа фамилии однозначно выделяется далеко не во всех случаях.

Comment: 3. В отношении того, что два НН не произносится - это, конечно, существенный момент, но ориентироваться следует прежде всего не на фонетическое, но графическое соответствие, т.е. именно на транслитерацию, вы же о нем и спрашиваете, не на транскрибирование. Сравните с латинской транслитерацией, вами же приведенной.

Comment: 4. БСЭ не аргумент. Тем более в том случае, когда разговор ведется о том, чего в ней нет. Посмотрите Википедию, пример ниже. Кстати, выкиньте из списка Тер-Ованесяна. Он родился и вырос на Украине, это как раз тот случай, когда было закреплено русское написние по фонетическому принципу, тут ни о какой транслитерации и речи быть не может.

Comment: 5. Повторюсь, вы возможно не заметили
Оваргар, а почему вы не возразили против написания фамилии через Е? Там же в оригинальном написании явное ի. - Например тут: Վահան Հովհաննիսյան http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BD,%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%AD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87
Это, кстати, и аргумент против предлагаемой вами   последовательности в передаче "однокоренных" слов.

Comment: Не возразил, так как иногда в арм. встречается вариант Ованесян, хотя больше распространен вариант с измененной гласной, т.е. с И, а также потому, что в данном вопросе меня интересует Н, а не гласные. С гласными проблем не бывает.

Comment: Ованисян Нар Михайлович. Арм. оперный певец.

Мурацан Григор (псевдоним; настоящая фамилия Тер-Ованисян). Арм. писатель.

Нар-Дос (псевдоним; настоящая фамилия и имя Ованисян Микаэл Захарьевич). Арм. писатель.

Это из вышеприведенного ответа. БСЭ весомее, так как над ней работали академики и ведущие специалисты в данной области, причем в советское время, когда связи между Москвой и Ереваном были гораздо более тесными, в отличие от Википедии, где каждый может написать как угодно.